# Cannot deserialize object with Json.Net

Tags: json, json.net

I have a very simple POCO class:

```
    [JsonArray]
    public class WebGame
    {    
        public  int Key { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Trying to deserialize to it a json string:

```
  string json = @"[{'Key':'1','Name':'WebGame','Description':'bla-bla-bla'}]";
  var myDeserializedObjList = (List<WebGame>)(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(List<WebGame>)));      
  var game = myDeserializedObjList[0];
```

I get an exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'WebGame' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the
>   JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so
>   that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer,
>   not a collection type like an array or List) that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [JsonArray] attribute and it would work fine